# Can I upload the file to the blob storage and give that path to the docusign instead of base64 or bytes

Tags: docusignapi

I have larger files it is taking too much time when I give base64 or even bytes. I am looking for an option where I can directly give bloburl to docusign envelope. If there is any option please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upload documents in binary format and from cloud providers.

### Cloud providers

DocuSign can load directly from

- Google Drive
- Dropbox
- Box
- OneDrive (Personal and Business)

[Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-give-docusign-access-to-your-cloud-storage). To use this feature as a developer, first set it up using the DocuSign web app. Then use DocuSign's [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see how the API calls reference the files on the cloud servers.

Also see the docs for the [Document.remoteUrl](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_documents_remoteurl)  attribute.

### Use multi-part mime format with the regular Envelopes:create call

Multi-part mime enables you to include one or more documents in binary format. [Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/rules-and-limits/requests/). Example using [Node.js](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/sendBinaryDocs.js). [Examples](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/send-binary/) for other languages are also available as part of the QuickStart code examples.

### Use Chunked Uploads

The [Chunked Uploads](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/chunkeduploads/) API resource enables you to upload a document in binary format, in multiple parts if needed, then use the resulting reference URL when creating an envelope.

The [API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com) uses chunked uploads. So you can monitor the API via [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) while using the API Request Builder to see what it is doing.

In any case, remember that there's a maximum request size for any API call to DocuSign of 34MB. There are other limits too. Discuss with your DocuSign contacts if you have any issues with limits.